# Process some background logic across multiple Activity

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-workmanager, background-task

I have some question during build some Application with Kotlin.

What I want to achieve is preserve my background task during change activities.

Below is the description.

```
--Launcher Activity A---
  > Trigger some essential logic for activity (execute 3rd party library or Network request)
    : Run Security Module
    : Get config from server
    : Check device root or not
    : and little bit more

  > After trigger these above event (but don't want to wait to receive result, execute only), 
    then start Activity B

-- Main Activity B---
  > I want to receive a result what I fired at Activity A.
    : Handle security module state (successfully run, fail, root device... and so on ...)
    : Update UI with initial Config and so on...
```

What I thought is, write a logic at Application Component with Flow or LiveData,
and then collect or observe the result from Activities.

But... have no confidence this method is acceptable or not.

(in case of memory leak, design pattern...)

So I want some advice about this approach ......
(Why I want to execute only from A and don't wait its result, is for performance. Speed up to represent Main Activity to user.)

Thx in Advance!

Comment: I would say a singleton class which can be triggered to get the newest config rom the server and holds it as a state is the right way to do. All classes that are interested in the state can get the Service and get the state as an observable value (like Flow) which then contains the latest received value or an `EmptyState` if call is not finished.

Comment: @DanielKnauf Thx for answering. I'll try ur advise, and then come back!!!

Comment: good luck! I'm currently in Seoul but only until Sunday morning. If you like to discuss the topic in person :)

Comment: @DanielKnauf oh u stay in Seoul now? Hope u have a great day here! And now i'm struggle to achieve it...

Comment: was here two month, because my girlfriend worked here and I rom here for my German company. Will probably come again in the future. Where are you struggling?